# Cannot update table with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have 2 tables, `user` and `user_role`:

```
user = id, name, pass
user_role= user_role_id, user_role_name
```

I'm trying update the tables with the following query:

```
UPDATE users SET nom = ?, user_role_id = ?, pass = ? WHERE id = ?
```

**My PHP code:**

```
$nom = $_POST['nom']; $roles = $_POST['roles'];$pass = $_POST['pass'];  
$valid = true; if (empty($nom)) { $nameError = 'Entrée un nom'; $valid = 
false; }
else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nom)){ $nameError = "que des letttres 
sans espace"; } 
if(empty($pass)){ $passError ='entrée un mot de pass'; $valid= false; }
else if (!preg_match('$S*(?=S{8,})(?=S*[a-z])(?=S*[A-Z])(?=S*[d])(?=S* 
[W])S*$', $pass)) 
if (!isset($roles)) { $rolesError = 'Selectionner un roles'; $valid = 
false; } 
if ($valid) { $pdo = Database::connect(); $pdo- 
>setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

 $sql = "UPDATE users 
 SET nom = ?, user_role_id = ?, pass = ? WHERE id = ?";

            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($id,$nom, $roles,$pass));
            Database::disconnect();
```

I got no errors but the table is not updated

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: And show your PHP code

Comment: You have the paramaters as well otherwise its not gonna work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "nom" column defined?

I think "nom" is actually "name" column of users, am I wrong?

also the order of variables in array is wrong. code should be as follows

```
$sql = "UPDATE users  SET name = ?, user_role_id = ?, pass = ? WHERE id = ?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($nom, $roles,$pass,$id));
Database::disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you update columns that are not in the table being updated?  I assume you are using MySQL.  If so, you can update multiple tables at the same time:

```
UPDATE users u JOIN
       user_roles ur
       ON ur.user = u.id
    SET u.nom = ?,
        ur.user_role_id = ?,
        u.pass = ?
    WHERE u.id = ?
```